# Why does Shamir's Trick for RSA Work

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic

I have read that Shamir's trick can protect RSA with CRT against fault attacks. However, it is not clear to me why the following equations
$$
s_{p}^{*}=m^{d \bmod \varphi(p \cdot t)} \bmod p \cdot t \\
s_{q}^{*}=m^{d \bmod \varphi(q \cdot t)} \bmod q \cdot t
$$
imply that:
$$
s_{p}^{*} = s_{q}^{*} \bmod t
$$

Comment: That's not Shamir's trick as I know it, which computes $x^a\,y^b\bmod n$ at roughly 60% the cost of computing it as $(x^a\bmod n)\,y^b\bmod n$. OTOH Shamir surely has many tricks. Also, while the equation stated holds, that's not the standard countermeasure against fault attacks, which is to check $s^e\bmod n=m$.

Comment: @fgrieu It is named Shamir's trick in [Topics in Cryptology – CT-RSA 2009](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-00862-7) and that's where I got the name from.

Comment: Yes, I now see it's in Matthieu Rivain, [Securing RSA against Fault Analysis by
Double Addition Chain Exponentiation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/165.pdf) (updated version), originally [in proceedings of CT-RSA 2009](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-00862-7_31). Still, [this reference](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-5906-5_1157) makes _Shamir's Trick_ synonymous of [_Simultaneous Exponentiation_](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-5906-5_45).

Comment: Update: and [that reference too](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44647-8_11), in [it's note 1](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44647-8_11.pdf#Hfootnote.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\varphi(t)|\varphi(pt)$ and $\varphi(t)|\varphi(qt)$ so that if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the exponents for $s_p^*$ and $s_q^*$ then $d=d_1+k_1\varphi(t)$ and $d=d_2+k_2\varphi(t)$ for some integers $k_1$ and $k_2$. It follows that $d_1=d_2+(k_2-k_1)\varphi(t)$ and hence
$$d_1\equiv d_2\pmod{\varphi(t)}.$$

It follows that $m^{d_1}\equiv m^{d_2}\pmod t$ by Euler's theorem.

Comment: I just realized that I don't really understand why $d_1\equiv d_2\pmod{\phi(t)}$ could you explain this further? Thank you!